# Can't print the stringMatching pattern

Tags: python, algorithm, string-matching

When i run this code I didn't get any error, but I can't print out my code on below.

I've tried to change condition places change but didn't work. Where is my mistake and how to fix it?

```py
def stringMatching(text, pattern):
  for i in range (len(text) - len(pattern)):
  j = 0
  while j < len(pattern) & pattern[j] == text[i+j]:
    j = j + 1
  if j == len(pattern):
    return -1
string = "Chapter I. The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog."
substr = "over the"
print(stringMatching([string],[substr]))
```

Comment: Your possible return values from your function are either -1 if the `j==len(pattern)` is met, or `None`. You presumably want to return something so that you can print it. You also need to fix your indentation in the code above as it's obviously not right.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you're looking for substrings, you can just use the find() method like below:

```
print(string.find(substr))
```

if the result is > -1, it is a substring. You can also make a function if you want just a return 0/ -1 like so:

```
string = "Chapter I. The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog."
substr = "over the"
substr2 = "lazy hat"

def checkSubstring(string, substring):
    if string.find(substring) > -1:
        print("Within the Text")
        return 0
    else:
        print("Not within the Text")
        return -1

checkSubstring(string, substr)
checkSubstring(string, substr2)
```

which returns 0 and -1 respectively

Comment: oh thank you so much, code runs correctly, what about if we try to run it in only 1 function? Can't we make some edits on the first part without second function?

Comment: what exactly do you mean? If you mean can we just use the string.find() method then you would just have to use the logic that less than 0 means the second string isnt a substring

Comment: I mean without a checkSubstring function could we just include those operations to stringMatching function? By the way your code is fine Im appreciate for good programming.

Comment: I think I'm still a little confused as to what you mean. Could you explain it more explicitly

Comment: Ofcourse, I mean without create a new function to print out what is going on in the output, could we just add some code in the stringMatching function that I wrote on above, without adding a new function such as you wrote above as checkSubstring? I am trying to make a function which has output with it (not None).

Comment: If youre just looking to add some sort of print() output you could just add a print() line before the return to the function I defined above and remove the print call for actually calling the function. I can edit my answer if you're confused by what I just said

Comment: Can you do it please, I really wonder with that way, thank you!

Comment: Ive edited the code above. Now you can print the results you want. Is this what you wanted?

Comment: Almost what i dreamed was this, thank you for your support and energy, have a nice day!